# How to configure the timeout on a camel cxf endpoint

Tags: java, http, apache-camel, cxf

I have a soap client developed using apache camel cxf component
The client's service that we are invoking takes too much time to respond and I was asked to increase the timeout of the invocation

I tried to use a custom cxfEndpointConfigurer for the cxf ToEndPoint as following : cxf://http://localhost:6025/MyMockService?cxfEndpointConfigurer=#MyCxfConfigurer&dataFormat=MESSAGE&portName=%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Forg.tempuri%7DMyServiceSoap11&serviceName=%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Forg.tempuri%7DMyServiceService

and here is the code bellow :

public class TemplateEndpointConfigurer implements CxfEndpointConfigurer {

```
@Override
public void configure(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory factoryBean) {
    // Do nothing here
}

@Override
public void configureClient(Client client) {

    final HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

    final HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    policy.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
    policy.setReceiveTimeout(300000);
    policy.setConnection(ConnectionType.CLOSE);
    conduit.setClient(policy);

}

@Override
public void configureServer(Server server) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

But I still get a timeout error after 60000ms which is the cxf default

do you have any idea how I can set successfully set this timeout ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same issue had occurred to me and i was able to fix it by setting the `Client.REQUEST_CONTEXT` header as below:

This can be done in a processor/bean defined in the route before calling the web service :

```
    public void setWebServiceTimeout(Exchange exchange) {
      Map<String, Object> requestContext = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      HTTPClientPolicy clientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
      clientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(300000);
      requestContext.put(HTTPClientPolicy.class.getName(), clientPolicy);
      exchange.getIn().setHeader(Client.REQUEST_CONTEXT , requestContext);
}
```

Comment: Hello Parasanth , thanks for your answer , I confirm that it works and I opted for it
Also the solution for the first approach is to put ""cxfConfigurer=#MyCxfConfigurer" rather than"cxfEndpointConfigurer=#MyCxfConfigurer" as camel property